# Should I delete handler while removing element?

Tags: jquery

I'm working just few days with jQuery, so question might be not very interesting.
I have **DIV** reloaded on button press over ajax. **DIV** content itself registers **click** handler for button. So the question is: should I remove handler which loaded content had registered?

I make little experiment and looks like I shouldn't. But is it really true?

Comment: If elements are removed from the DOM and you have no further references to them, the event handlers will eventually be garbage collected as well.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am not good in js. How reference in js looks like?

Comment: For example `var someElement = document.getElementById('someId')`. Even if the element is removed by your update process, `someElement` will still hold a reference to that element and have access to its associated data.

Comment: are you saying that the DIV is receiving the click function also? If that's the case, you probably want to use e.stopPropagation(), from the docs -> [Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks a lot. Thats what I want.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, usefull advice but thats not what I mean. P.S. cool nick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If elements are removed from the DOM and you have no further references to them, the event handlers will eventually be garbage collected as well.

But if you have a reference, like

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('someId')
```

then even if the element is removed by your update process, `someElement` will still hold a reference to that element. This also means that the event handlers still exist in memory.